# Hessenberg matrix with householder transformation on Hermitian matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have written a program to find a Hessenberg matrix who's orthogonal equivalent with a matrix A using householder transformations. The program works fine until I start using Hermitian matrices. Normally, when using hermitian matrices, the hessenberg matrix should be tridiagonal but mine only has zeros at some places of the first row (and of course below the subdiagonal). Can anyone help me?
My householder function is defined as:

```
function [H,Q]=householder(A)

[m,n] = size(A);

Q=eye(n);

for k = 1:n-2

  x=A(k+1:n,k);

  [sz,szz] = size(x);
  e_k = zeros(sz,1);
  e_k(1)=1;

  u = (x+sign(x(1))*norm(x)*e_k)/(norm(x+sign(x(1))*norm(x)*e_k));

  I=eye(sz);   

  P=I-2*(u)*(u');

  Q_temp=blkdiag(eye(k),P);
  Q=Q_temp*Q;
  A=(Q_temp')*A*(Q_temp);

end
  H=A;

end
```

I make a random Hermitian matrix:

```
function RHM=RandomHermitianMatrix(n)
   A=complex(rand(n,n),(rand(n,n)*2)-1);
   for k=1:n-1
     vct=diag(A,k);
     for l=1:n-k
        A(l+k,l)=conj(vct(l));
     end
   end
   RHM=A;
end
```

I test it using:

```
function message = test_householder_hermitian(n)
   tic;
   tst=RandomHermitianMatrix(n)
   tstt=householder(tst)
   toc

   message='done';
end
```

Thanks a lot!